# How to Format the one column in to currency column in datagridview c#.net win apps

Tags: datagridview, currency-formatting

In my datagridview one column working with format property, in another column it doesnt work why?
i tried this one

```
 private void dgvItemDtls_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
          dgvItemDtls.Columns["SlNO"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";

          dgvItemDtls.Columns["Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
    }
```

From above code Formate is working in **Columns["SlNO"]** but not working for **Columns["Price"]** why i dont understand,but i want **Columns["Price"]** will be currency column plzz can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can format the column in design time.